# Need help in displaying last 5 rows. PHP, MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, rows

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong. I would like to display the last 5 rows in desc order.

```
$pull_activity_logs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM activity_logs WHERE ac_no = '$logined_acc' order by id desc       limit 0,5") 
or die(mysql_error());  
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $pull_activity_logs )) {
$activity_time = $row["datetime"];
$activity = $row["activity"];
}
echo "$activity";
```

Help would be deeply appreciated

Comment: I know this doesn't solve your problem, but I highly disencourage you of using mysql_query() - just like PHP guys does in here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php - it's deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0 and will be removed in the future

Comment: Probably a typo in the query? check also if $logined_acc is actually defined, the query syntax is ok

Comment: I don't know what kind of problem you are facing?
echo "$activity"; statement is outside of loop. you will see always last value of 5.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can always select the *first* five in *asc* order, that would be last five in desc order, and then you could reverse their order in php if needed (5 values isnt anything what an array couldn't handle)

CODE:

```
$pull_activity_logs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM activity_logs WHERE ac_no = '$logined_acc' order by id asc limit 5"); 
$temp_arr = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $pull_activity_logs )) {
  $temp_arr[] = $row; //add to end
}
$final_arr = array_reverse($temp_arr);
foreach($final_arr as $row) //this doesn't have to be named $row
  $activity_time = $row["datetime"];
  $activity = $row["activity"];
  echo "$activity";
}
```

EDIT:

now when i look at it maybe whole problem was in wring position of your echo:

```
$pull_activity_logs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM activity_logs WHERE ac_no = '$logined_acc' order by id desc limit 0,5") 
or die(mysql_error());  
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $pull_activity_logs )) {
  $activity_time = $row["datetime"];
  $activity = $row["activity"];
echo "$activity"; //this goes INSIDE the loop
}
```

Comment: That or use concatenation assignment `.=` on  `$activity`. And initialize it before the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the first five in ascending order and *then* order them in SQL by using a subquery:

```
select al.*
from (SELECT al.*
      FROM activity_logs al
      WHERE ac_no = '$logined_acc'
      order by id asc
      limit 0, 5
     ) al
order by id desc;
```